# Setting X and y for training CNN based on images and subfolder names in Keras

Tags: python, keras

The following snippet of code gives me 150 images belonging to three classes (there are three subfolders with 50 images in each - the folders are named after the classes of Iris that I'm trying to write a CNN to classify).

The question I have is how do I set np arrays of the images as my X and the subfolder names as my y for training my CNN?

```
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
shear_range = 0.2, zoom_range = 0.2, horizontal_flip = True)
test_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_gen.flow_from_directory(r"Iris_Imgs",
target_size = (5, 5), shuffle=True, batch_size = 15, class_mode = 'binary')
train_imgs, train_labels = next(training_set)
test_set = test_gen.flow_from_directory(r"Iris_Imgs",
target_size = (5, 5), shuffle=True, class_mode = 'binary')
test_imgs, test_labels = next(test_set)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using flow_from_directory incorrectly. Unless your data is already grouped in subfolders, flow_from_directory will not work properly.

Use flow_from_dataframe. Store path to images in one column and class_labels in another column. Then use flow_from_dataframe. This is what you should be using since your data is not classified in subfolders.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - however my images are grouped in subfolders (3 subfolders named Setosa, Versicolor, and Virginica). The subfolder names are the classes I'm trying to train my CNN to perform classification on.

Comment: In that case, do not use class_mode = 'binary'. You have three classes. Try using class_mode = 'categorical'

Comment: Also, your test data seems to be taken from train data. Your model will overfit if thats the case

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes I realized the test data part - this is for an assignment so the data is very simple. We're just working on implementing a CNN at this point. 

After using class_mode = 'categorical' do you know how I fit this data to my CNN? Is there an X. y to place in the following line?: 

model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=15)

or am I thinking about it wrong?

Comment: Since you are using generators, there is no need for X,y. Both of them are stored in train_gen and the model will automatically get both X and y values. You'll have to use steps_per_epochs = len(train_gen) and validation_steps = len(val_gen). Both of them have to be calculated. Look at the documentaion of ImageDataGenerator for understanding the fit_generator. fit_generator will be deprecated soon . You can use fit instead of fit_generator and it will work the same